# Question about the problem of creating multiple collectionView in one viewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I created two collectionviews in one viewController. But I had a simple problem.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if collectionView == self.collectionView {
            let mainCell = collectionView
                .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuse.identifier.mainBookCell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! MainBookCell

            let url = URL(string: booksGenre?.books[indexPath.row].bookImage ?? "")
            mainCell.bookImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)

            return mainCell

        } else if collectionView == self.aLotViewCollectionView {
            let aLotViewCell = collectionView
                .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuse.identifier.mainBookCell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! ALotViewCell

            let url = URL(string: booksGenre?.books[indexPath.row].bookImage ?? "")
            aLotViewCell.bookImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)

            return aLotViewCell
        }
//problem!! return ?????
    }
```

```
Missing return in a function expected to return 'UICollectionViewCell'
```

What should you return from where the problem occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only ever going to have 2 collectionViews, you can do

```
if collectionView == self.collectionView {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Or change it to a switch statement:

```
switch collectionView {
    case self.collectionView: 
        // do something collectionView
    default: 
        // do something for aLotViewCollectionView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return UICollectionViewCell(), or you could put a fatalError() to make sure you catch the error in the case that the function is called with another collection view.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only two, you should not need the "else if".  Remove the "if" so it is only else.

From:

```
else if collectionView == self.aLotViewCollectionView {
            let aLotViewCell = collectionView
                .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuse.identifier.mainBookCell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! ALotViewCell

            let url = URL(string: booksGenre?.books[indexPath.row].bookImage ?? "")
            aLotViewCell.bookImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)

            return aLotViewCell
        }
```

To:

```
else {
        let aLotViewCell = collectionView
            .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuse.identifier.mainBookCell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! ALotViewCell

        let url = URL(string: booksGenre?.books[indexPath.row].bookImage ?? "")
        aLotViewCell.bookImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)

        return aLotViewCell
    }
```